# Migrating Chrome Extension to Firefox

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, xul

I have a chrome extension with a manifest.json file containing basically this:

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["*://mail.google.com/mail/*"],
  "js": ["safegmailbootstrap.js","cryptojs/rollups/aes.js", "javascrypt/aes.js", "javascrypt/md5.js", "javascrypt/aesprng.js", "javascrypt/jscrypt.js", "javascrypt/entropy.js"]
}
```

I'm trying to build a firefox extension, I've created all the structures, but still can't make it work in firefox.

I think I'm writing the XUL file in /chrome/content wrong.

I've tried writing it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<overlay id="sample" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
<script src="safegmailbootstrap.js" />
<script src="cryptojs/rollups/aes.js" />
<script src="javascrypt/aes.js" />
<script src="javascrypt/md5.js" />
<script src="javascrypt/aesprng.js" />
<script src="javascrypt/jscrypt.js" />
<script src="javascrypt/entropy.js" />
</overlay>
```

I don't know which is the analogous of json chrome file "matches" to firefox extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find it easier using the addon SDK:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/page-mod.html

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder

Comment: Explain me something... Will I'll be writing an add on or an extension in firefox??

Comment: They are not really the same anymore. "There are currently several toolsets for developing Firefox add-ons, but [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) will become the standard by the end of 2017. The other toolsets, including overlay add-ons, bootstrapped add-ons, and the Add-on SDK, are expected to be deprecated over the same period of time." and "We are planning to deprecate the use by Firefox add-ons of the techniques described in this document. Don't use these techniques to develop new add-ons. Use WebExtensions instead."